# Locust gevent syntax?

Tags: python, websocket, locust

I successfully run locust for a GET request on the same domain, both with docker and locally.
But I can't make it work with websocket.

My locustfile.py:

```
import time, websocket
from locust import HttpUser, task, between, events
from websocket import create_connection
import gevent

class QuickstartUser(HttpUser):
    wait_time = between(1, 5)
    @task
    def on_start(self):
       ws = create_connection('wss://REDACTED.com')
       g = gevent.spawn(self.connect)
       g.get(block=True, timeout=10)
       g = gevent.spawn(self.subscribe)
       g.get(block=True, timeout=10)
       g = gevent.spawn(self.send)
       g.get(block=True, timeout=10)       
       
    def _receive():
       while True:
          res = ws.recv()
          events.request_success.fire(
             request_type='Websocket Receive Message',
             name='test websocket message receive',
             response_time=0,
             response_length=len(res)

    gevent.spawn(_receive)
```

(taken from https://medium.com/@rajatsaxena120/websockets-in-python-d91c7bc2fd22)

I keep getting:

```
  File "./locustfile.py", line 27
    gevent.spawn(_receive)
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I also noticed that websocket is missing from the docker image, how could I add `pip install websocket-client` when the container exit as soon as the py file is incorrect?

Thanks!

Comment: Count your parentheses!

Comment: Yes, it looks like the parentheses are the problem.  Where is the ending parenthesis for `events.request_success.fire(`?  I have fixed it in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66426943/14469685)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're simply missing the ending parenthesis for the line that says

```py
events.request_success.fire(
```

Here's your code fixed:

```py
import time, websocket
from locust import HttpUser, task, between, events
from websocket import create_connection
import gevent

class QuickstartUser(HttpUser):
    wait_time = between(1, 5)
    @task
    def on_start(self):
       ws = create_connection('wss://REDACTED.com')
       g = gevent.spawn(self.connect)
       g.get(block=True, timeout=10)
       g = gevent.spawn(self.subscribe)
       g.get(block=True, timeout=10)
       g = gevent.spawn(self.send)
       g.get(block=True, timeout=10)       
       
    def _receive():
       while True:
          res = ws.recv()
          events.request_success.fire(
             request_type='Websocket Receive Message',
             name='test websocket message receive',
             response_time=0,
             response_length=len(res)
          )
    gevent.spawn(_receive)
```

Comment: You're right, not my fault, check the link above. NOw I get   
```
File "/media/pm/Data/DockerVolumes/locust/locustfile.py", line 20, in _receive
    res = ws.recv()
NameError: name 'ws' is not defined
```

Comment: @phm: I'm pretty sure that the problem is that `ws` is in a different function, but I don't know much about locust.  Maybe try global variables?